# How to attach a received mail as an attachment to a new mail using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, email-attachments

I have a `(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mail)` mail object.
I want this mail to attach as an attachment to another mail.
but not able to find any solution.So can anyone please help.

I have created another mail object as shown below :
`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem toSendMail = this.Application.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement you want to send an existing mail object as an attachment to another mail in outlook.

One way of doing this is by saving the existing mailItem as an attachment to other. Try this:

```
private void AddMessageAsAttachment(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem 
                     mailContainer,Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailToAttach)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachments attachments = null;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment attachment = null;
            try
            {
                attachments = mailContainer.Attachments;
                attachment = attachments.Add(mailToAttach,
                   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olEmbeddeditem, 1, "The attached e-mail");
                mailContainer.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (attachment != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(attachment);
                if (attachments != null) Marshal.ReleaseComObject(attachments);
            }
        }
```

reference : https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/12/how-to-add-existing-e-mail-message-as-attachment/

Comment: Do not write answers that contain only a link. Try to summarize additionally the most relevant information.

Comment: @StefanG I have edited the answer with relevant code for better reference and also the source of reference.

Answer (score 0):

Get the mail, which should be added as attachment. 
then call «SaveAs({filename}, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olMSG)» and add this file to your new mail

Comment: Is there any direct method without using saveas mail.

Comment: I don't think it's possible with the outlook interop lib. create a temporary file , attach it, send the mail, delete the file